# Getting undefined when accessing redux stores state property in react App

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux in my react app and I am getting undefined when I access redux state property in one of my component, why is that? the state is valid when I call console.log in reducer file : here is my reducerFile :

```
const initState = {
    isCurrentUser : true
}
export default function(state=initState, action) {


    console.log(`this is from localAuthReducer ${state.isCurrentUser}`)
    switch(action.type) {
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Here is my react component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './IndexPage.module.scss';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './../../components/Header/Header';



class IndexPage extends Component {


render() {
       return(

           <div className={styles.container}>


                <Header

                 isCurrentUser = {this.props.isCurrentUser}
                 />

                { console.log(`this is from indexPage ${this.props.isCurrentUser}`)}


           </div>

       );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isCurrentUser : state.isCurrentUser
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(IndexPage);
```

Here is my index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App/App';
import {Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)
);




ReactDOM.render(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App />
                </Provider>
                , document.querySelector("#root"));
```

I dont know where I am going wrong isCurrentUser must have value of true as it is the default value of the redux state

Comment: What exactly is undefined? Please, post exact error message.

Comment: { console.log(`this is from indexPage ${this.props.isCurrentUser}`)} this in the browser shows as undefined

Comment: checkout react component code I have pasted

Comment: console.log(`this is from localAuthReducer ${state.isCurrentUser}`) this code returns true in my reducer file

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem - Stackblitz, etc. The code you posted should work ok.

Comment: ok I got it . function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(`this from mstp ${Object.keys(state.authReducer)}`)
    return {
        isCurrentUser : state.authReducer.isCurrentUser
    }
}

Comment: instead of state.isCurrentUser I used state.authReducer.isCurrentUser

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Comment: I am also facing this problem now, trying to find out answers.
Will let u know once I get any.